# Access VBA Errors: Expression refers to an object that is closed

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, runtime-error

I'm running into an error, when I try to open a form and have the data entered go into the current record on my AUS_Table. The error keeps saying "Me.ID = Expression refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist"...but it definitely exists on my AUS_Table as the first field.

```
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
DoCmd.OpenForm "6_FEHB", , , "[ID]=" & Me.ID
DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
```

I do have an expression on my first form (1_Introduction), then when you click the command button BEGIN, it clears the table completely (as I don't need to keep this data long term, and want it to clear before the next user inputs their data). Would it have anything to do with that?

```
Private Sub Begin_Click()
'DELETE PREVIOUS TABLE DATA
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM [AUS_Table];"
' OPEN BASIC INFO FORM
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="2_Basic_Info"
End Sub
```

Comment: I should add, I have two tables associated with the forms. The first table ‘UPDMS_Fulltime’ is associated with the first form after my introduction and pre-populates fields in the form based on the name drop down. The second table, AUS_table, is a blank table that I want all the rest of the forms (form 3-10) to add data into the table once the user types data into the fields of the form.

Once you click ‘next’ on the form associated with the UPDMS table, it’ll take you to the following forms I want associated with the AUS_table.

Comment: Never simultaneous users? Is this a split database? Have you step debugged?

Comment: Never simultaneous users, and unsure what split database is. The debugging just highlights my DoCmd.OpenForm "6_FEHB", , , "[ID]=" & Me.ID line

Comment: Sounds like can't find a control named ID. I always name controls different from field, such as tbxID. What event is problem code in? Clearing table should not be an issue.

Comment: I’m wondering if that is the issue. The field name is ID on my table, is that different than a control?

Comment: Yes, controls are things like textboxes, comboboxes, etc. Textboxes and comboboxes can be bound to fields. This is basic Access functionality.